# ATA errors on Debian 6 Xen host, but disks are fine

Tags: hard-drive

A Debian 6 machine with software RAID1 we manage (but don't have physical access to) is spewing out all kinds of errors about the disks (both ATA1 and ATA2).

I have no idea what this could be. The disks seem to be fine. We haven't noticed hangs or whatever with the websites the server is serving.

I know this is a 'could be anything' question, but I really hope someone is able to help me.

Specs:

1. Debian 6, running Xen hypervisor
2. Disks: 250 GB WDC WD2500AAKX-00U6AA0
3. NCQ supported and enabled: ata2.00: 488397168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
4. SATA controller: Intel Corporation Patsburg 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
5. Kernel: 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64
6. Ram: 16GB
7. Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz

Here are some of the errors:

```
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x3 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: cmd 61/08:00:98:1f:5e/00:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 out
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]           res 40/00:0c:58:3a:62/00:00:0d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: cmd 61/08:08:58:3a:62/00:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 4096 out
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]           res 40/00:0c:58:3a:62/00:00:0d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1: hard resetting link
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[2013-05-13 21:36:17]  ata1: EH complete
```

and

```
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x40f SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: cmd 61/58:00:48:c4:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 45056 out
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]           res 40/00:1c:78:cb:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: cmd 61/10:08:78:c8:6b/01:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 139264 out
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]           res 40/00:1c:78:cb:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: cmd 61/b0:10:c8:ca:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 90112 out
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]           res 40/00:1c:78:cb:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: cmd 61/58:18:78:cb:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 45056 out
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]           res 40/00:1c:78:cb:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: cmd 61/b0:50:c8:c7:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq 90112 out
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]           res 40/00:1c:78:cb:6b/00:00:0d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1: hard resetting link
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[2013-05-15 08:58:29]  ata1: EH complete
```

and

```
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x3 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: cmd 61/58:00:e8:75:93/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 45056 out
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]           res 40/00:0c:40:76:93/00:00:12:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: cmd 61/b0:08:40:76:93/00:00:12:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 90112 out
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]           res 40/00:0c:40:76:93/00:00:12:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2: hard resetting link
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[2013-05-19 01:21:19]  ata2: EH complete
```

SMART doesn't give any errors. Here's smart of SDA (SDB is similar):

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD2500AAKX-00U6AA0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC2H0107714
Firmware Version: 15.01H15
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes

ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   145   145   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3750
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       3430
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   110   108   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

And the sda interface errors:

```
# smartctl -l sataphy /dev/sda
smartctl 5.40 2010-07-12 r3124 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-10 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

General Purpose Logging (GPL) feature set supported
SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2          165  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2          165  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x000a  2           49  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2           79  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x8000  4     12672920  Vendor specific
```

and sdb:

```
# smartctl -l sataphy /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.40 2010-07-12 r3124 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-10 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

General Purpose Logging (GPL) feature set supported
SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2           45  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2           45  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            2  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            2  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x000a  2           46  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2           22  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x8000  4     12672927  Vendor specific
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handshake would seem to suggest that the controller is having trouble talking to the drives. I'd suspect electrical interference, bad cables, or possibly a bad controller. In the latter case the motherboard would need to be replaced. You'll only find the culprit by a process of elimination, by testing each piece of hardware separately.

Comment: I guess you're right. We don't have access to the machine, so I guess the provider is just going to have to put the disks in another one. I wonder if I'll be able to get them to do that...

Comment: To verify whether the error is related to the interface between the disk and the controller, try `smartctl -l sataphy /dev/sda`.

Comment: Could be as simple as the SATA cables running tightly packed together inside the casing. Had this just last week. New system put together by my colleague who is a neatness freak. He tie-wrapped the 4 SATA cables in a tight bundle every 5 cm to a rail inside the case. Cables interfered with each other.

Comment: @RaymondTau I've added that info. I didn't know that feature existed, and I'm not able to interpret it :) There are CRC errors on both drives, but I still don't know whose fault it is.

Comment: @Halfgaar I would guess that means the communication interface between the drive and the controller had experienced some error. Then, try to reseat the SATA cables on both end first, then goes on with other pieces of components.